# Problem about multiplication of functions in Sobolev spaces and regularity related to gauge theory

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, gauge-theory

Let $X$ be a closed Riemannian 4-manifold.

Let $f\in L^2_k(X)$ (Sobolev space of maps $X\to \mathbb{C}$ of regularity $k$), with  $k>2$. Suppose also that $f|_{\mathcal O} \not\equiv 0$ for any open set $\mathcal{O}\subseteq X$.

Let $G_r := \{u: X\to \mathbb{C} \ | u\in L^2_r(X), \ |u(x)|= 1 \ \forall x\in X\}$
where $r\geq 3$, so that $G_r$ consists of continuous functions and is also a Lie group.

Now, $G_{k+1}$ acts (smoothly) on $L^2_k(X)$ by multiplication.

> Suppose that $u\in G_3$ and $uf \in L^2_k$ (so we gained regularity if $k>3$), does this imply that $u \in G_{k+1}$?

To understand the motivation behind this question, think of $G_{k+1}$ as the "gauge  group" acting on $L^2_k(X)$,  then $f$ is gauge equivalent to $\tilde {u} f$ if $\tilde u \in G_{k+1}$. Then the question asks if the orbits of the $G_{k+1}$ action are sensitive to the regularity of the gauge transformations $G_r$.

Comment: With the new condition, it seems like you're trying to get at "dividing by $f$"? So if $f$ is not identically 0 on every open set, then can you not do: define the function $1/f$, then $u=uf \cdot 1/f$ and use the Sobolev multiplication theorem? What goes wrong with this process? Does it just not give you enough derivatives?

Comment: @Keshav, the problem is the inversion, I don't think it is a continuous operator, or at least not between the same Sobolev spaces. 
I was hoping an analyst or somebody more used to Sobolev spaces to shed some light on that. 
Can you recommend me  a reference about the continuity of the map $f\mapsto 1/f$ between Sobolev spaces?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right - the answer is **no**. That's basically because the product $uf$ only carries partial information about the behavior of  $u$.

If

- $u$ is smooth except some small ball $B$,
- $f$ is smooth everywhere,
- $f \equiv 0$ on a neighborhood of $B$,

then the product $uf$ is also smooth, in particular it's in any space $L^2_k$. However, $u$ can have arbitrary regularity on $B$, so one can have $u \in L^2_3$ and not more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I should add that $ f$ cannot vanish in an open set (in the setting I am considering $f$ satisfies a PDE and by analytic continuation if such thing happens then $f$ would be identically $0$). I'll edit the question, please leave your answer as it is relevant anyway.